# Determine last date/time a stored procedure was compiled

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Is it possible to know when a Stored Procedure was last compiled?  (read: Changed)?  I see no fields in RDB$PROCEDURES but maybe there is some other way?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way.

Comment: One way would be to add DDL Alter procedure trigger (introduced in 3.0) http://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.Firebird30DDLTriggers

Comment: @Mariuz unfortunately we are on 2.54 but that interesting to know that for future when eventually we update to 3